# How can I extrapolate the transformation matrix from a MeshLab project file containing two aligned meshes?

Tags: matrix, alignment, mesh, meshlab

I have two meshes: mesh **A** and mesh **B**.

I'm working with MeshLab and all I need is to align them and then **extrapolate a transformation matrix that brings B on A**.

When I use the alignment tool, I **glue** A and I set it as the **base mesh**.
Then I perform the point base glueing on B and optionally I use the **process** button.
At the end of the procedure, I save the MeshLab project.

In order to extrapolate the transformation matrix that brings B on A, I just open the .mlp project file (it's a plain text file actually) and I read the data. Unfortunately, what I get is **not** what I expect.
There are two meshes, of course, A and B. For each of them there is a transformation matrix. I expect that mesh A (the one glued and set as base mesh) has an identity matrix, while mesh B has the transformation matrix needed to bring B on A.
Sometimes, the matrix of mesh A is close to identity, but still not the identity one.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE MeshLabDocument>
<MeshLabProject>
 <MeshGroup>
  <MLMesh label="A" filename="A.stl">
   <MLMatrix44>
1 3.61241e-09 1.85292e-11 -5.04461e-08 
-3.61241e-09 1 3.45518e-10 1.03514e-07 
-1.85292e-11 -3.45518e-10 1 5.35603e-09 
0 0 0 1 
</MLMatrix44>
  </MLMesh>
  <MLMesh label="B" filename="B.stl">
   <MLMatrix44>
-0.670956 -0.741136 -0.0231387 78.366 
0.738444 -0.665039 -0.111463 24.2717 
0.0672212 -0.0918734 0.993499 33.6056 
0 0 0 1 
</MLMatrix44>
  </MLMesh>
 </MeshGroup>
 <RasterGroup/>
</MeshLabProject>
```

**Now, my simple assumption is that for some reason MeshLab can't properly bring B onto A. Instead it brings B very close to A, but it needs to minimally adjust A's position too for a best match.**

If so, in order to have the best B to A transformation I want to perform the following:

[B matrix] * INVERTED[A matrix] = [B on A matrix]

Is this correct?

Comment: Just to point this out: even when A has not _an exact_ identity, it is numerically equivalent (e.g., 3.61241e-09 is almost 0).

Comment: There are cases in current Meshlab where mesh A (which should be identity) is moved half a meter; I filed it as a bug on https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/1410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order matters. Matrix Mb brings mesh B to position p, Matrix Ma brings mesh A to position p. Likewise, Ma_invert brings a mesh from position p to the location of mesh A.

Apply Mb to **mesh B**, now it reached p:

**`B_transformed = Mb * B`**

Bring `B_transformed` from position **p** to the location of **mesh A**:

**`B_aligned = Ma_inverse * B_transformed`**

So the combined operation should look like:

**`B_aligned = Ma_inverse * Mb * B`**